# How to backup the first 3 of 5 partitions

Tags: partitioning, backup, dd

I'm figuring out how to backup the first 3 of 5 partitions, in order to be able to restore them in case of disk failure or in case I messed up my system. Partition 4 and 5 are setup in RAID 1 configuration and contain data, which is backed up on another disk.

I think I should use the procedure below. My question is whether this works and will the RAID 1 configuration still work?

1. Get partition information:

> ```
> willem@willem-desktop:~$ sudo parted -l
> [sudo] password for willem:
> Model: ATA WDC WD10JFCX-68N (scsi)
> Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
> Partition Table: gpt
>
> Number Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
> 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32              boot
> 2      538MB   794MB  256MB  ext2
> 3      794MB   170GB  170GB                     lvm
> 4      170GB   485GB  315GB  btrfs
> 5      485GB   799GB  315GB  btrfs
> ```

2. Boot LiveUSB
3. Reduce entropy on partition 3:

> ```
> dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/delete.me bs=8M; rm delete.me
> ```

3. Calculate GPT table size
   Formula = (128*N)+1024 = (128*5)+1024 = 1664
4. Backup GPT table

> ```
> dd if=/dev/sda of=GPT_TABLE bs=1 count=1664
> ```

5. Backup partitions 1, 2 and 3

> ```
> dd if=/dev/sda1 | bzip2 > /media/sda1_image.bz2
> dd if=/dev/sda2 | bzip2 > /media/sda2_image.bz2
> dd if=/dev/sda3 | bzip2 > /media/sda3_image.bz2
> ```

6. If needed, restore GPT table

> ```
> dd  if=GPT_TABLE of=/dev/sda bs=1 count=1664
> ```

7. If needed, restore partitions 1, 2 and 3

> ```
> bzcat /media/sda1_image.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sda1
> bzcat /media/sda2_image.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sda1
> bzcat /media/sda3_image.bz2 | dd of=/dev/sda1
> ```